# Is there standalone (similar to yii) actions in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html

(reference to standalone actions in yii2)

Is there something similar to it in laravel 5

Comment: No not really. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to reuse my controllers. So I have, for example, NewsController and PostController and both of them has method `index(PostRepository $post)` and `index(NewsRepository $news)`. Without standalone actions I need to duplicate my code and tests for it. But having standalone atcion I will write something like `public $actions = ['index' => [IndexAction::class, 'news'=> NewsRepository::class]]`

Comment: No, Laravel has no such concept of putting actions into separate classes.

Instead, you can use traditional PHP inheritance or traits to solve the problem you mentioned above.